# DoesNotExist at /profile/1/ Profile matching query does not exist

Tags: django

My experience using Django is limited, but I hope I can explain my problem clearly. After successfully login to an application I am developing, I get re-directed to a user-page where I have different links. The error "DoesNotExist at /profile/1/ Profile matching query does not exist." occurs once I click on these links.

My model looks like this.

```
    from django.db import models
    from numpy import array
    from django.db.models import F
    from django.contrib.auth.models import User
    from user.models import Profile

    class Data(models.Model):
        posted_by = models.ForeignKey(User, null=True, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
        profile = models.ForeignKey(Profile, on_delete=models.CASCADE, null=True)
        Product = models.CharField(max_length=20, default="")
        item = models.CharField(max_length=20, null=True)
        quantity = models.IntegerField()
        price = models.IntegerField(default=0)
        total = models.IntegerField(editable=True,blank=True, null=True)
        date_created = date_created = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True, null=True)
    
        def __str__(self):
            return str(self.profile)
    
        def save(self, *args, **kwargs):
            self.total = self.price * self.quantity
            super().save(*args, **kwargs)
    
        @classmethod
        def get_projects(cls):
            projects = Data.objects.all()
            return projects
    
        @classmethod
        def find_projects(cls, search_term):
            project = Data.objects.filter(title__icontains=search_term)
            return project
            
    class Sales(models.Model):
        sales = models.IntegerField(default=0, blank=False, null=False)
        margin = models.IntegerField(editable=True, blank=True, null=True)
        user = models.ForeignKey(Profile,max_length= 20 ,null=False, on_delete=models.CASCADE, related_name='username')
        date_created = date_created = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True, null=True)
        
    
        def __str__(self):
            return str(self.user)
        
        def save(self, *args, **kwargs):
            self.margin = self.sales - Data.objects.get().total
            if self.sales > self.margin:
                
                self.margin =  self.margin
            else:
                -self.margin
            return super().save( *args, **kwargs)
```

UserModel is the profile model which I import into the Data model.

```
from django.db import models
from django.contrib.auth.models import User
from django.db.models import Avg
from django.db.models.signals import post_save

class Profile(models.Model):
    user = models.OneToOneField(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE, null=True,  related_name="user")
    profile_photo = models.ImageField(upload_to='profiles', null=True)
    bio = models.CharField(max_length=200, null=True)
    phone = models.PositiveIntegerField(default=0)

    def __str__(self):
        return str(self.user)

    def create_user_profile(sender, instance, created, **kwargs):

        if created:
            Profile.objects.create(user=instance)

        post_save.connect(create_user_profile, sender=User)

    def save_profile(self):
        self.save()

    @classmethod

    def get_profile(cls):
        profile = Profile.objects.all()
        return profile
```

MyView file has the code which is responsible for creating the profile.

```
def profile(request, id):
    user = request.user
    profile = Profile.objects.get(pk=id)
    projects = Data.objects.filter(id=profile)
    if request.method == "POST":
        profile_id = request.POST.get("user")
        profile_obj = Profile.objects.get(id=profile_id)
        profile_created, created = Data.objects.get_or_create(profile_id, user=user)
    context = {
        "profile":profile, "projects": projects
    }
    return render(request, "index.html", context)
```

This is the page which has the form to be rendered once a user clicks a link
MyHtmlPage:

```
 <div class="container">
          {% if messages %}
          <ul class="msg">
              {% for message in messages %}
              <li  {% if message.tags %} class=" {{ message.tags }} " {% endif %}> {{ message }} </li>
              {% endfor %}
          </ul>
        {% endif %}
        <form action="{% url 'profile'  %}" method= "POST" class="postform" enctype="multipart/form-data">
            
          <fieldset class="setfield">
            <legend class="legend"></legend>
            {% csrf_token %}
            
            {{ form.as_p }}
            <button type="submit" class="btn">Submit</button>
          </fieldset>
        </form>
        </div>
      
MyAppUrls:

 url(r'^$', views.home, name='home'),
    url(r'^profile/(?P<id>\d)/$', views.profile, name="profile"),
    url(r'^new/profile$', views.add_profile, name='add_profile'),
```

Answer (score 0):

Your post_save signal handler is declared inside the function that should be called, so it will never be called!
Register it somewhere else, typically in the ready method of the app class: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.1/ref/applications/#django.apps.AppConfig.ready

Comment: Thanks. Let me try this.